# Css Class Not Applied Anymore

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

i'am new in reactjs i face an issue while trying to follow along with CSS modules , in my case i run the command npm run eject commant then i configure my webpack.config.dev.js file and wepack.config.prod.js file

this is my App.CSS file

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
.red{
  color:red;
}

.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}


.button{
background-color :green;
color:white;
font:inherit;
border:1px solid blue;
padding:8px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.button:hover{
  background-color:red;
  color:black;
}
```

my App.js

the import of App.css :

```
import './App.css';




 return (
  <div className="App">
    
    <h1>Hell i am react newbie</h1>
    <p className={classes.join(' ')}>This is really working</p>
    <button className="button"
    //style={style}
    onClick={this.togglePerson}>Switch Name
    
     </button>
```

my webpack.config.dev.js file

```
 test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules : true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                },
              },
```

my wepack.config.prod.js

```
 test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              Object.assign(
                {
                  fallback: {
                    loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    options: {
                      hmr: false,
                      modules : true,
                      localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                    },
```

The css is not applied anymore after i run the command and configure the 2 files

Comment: In the CSS file...use button instead of .button